# Google Sheets. Conditional changing colur of text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet for a doing a monthly roster for a volunteer group.  Column A contains the volunteer names & Row 1 contains the days of the month.  I email out a request to volunteers to ask what days they can volunteer for the following month.  They respond with their dates.  They are asked to put as many days down as they can but they will only be rostered for 1 day for that month.

I put an small 'x' next to their name & for each day they have requested. As soon as I put the first 'x' in any date for that volunteer, I would like to change the font colour of their from black to blue.  This makes it easier to see which volunteers have not yet responded so I can chase them up.

When I have all the responses I will then go through & create the roster.  2-4 volunteers will rostered for each day.  When I have allocated a volunteer a day, I will capitalise the 'X'.  If using another letter is easier, that will be fine. When this is done I would like to change the font colour of their name from blue to green.  Also, I would like the font colour of the day in Row 1 to change from black to green.

How can I do this?  Many thanks.

Tony

Comment: Hi. Sharing an example spreadsheet would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, trying to explain "How [you can] do this" in a void would be difficult or vague at best.